# PhoneGap - Invoke external scanning app and receive scanned value

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, barcode-scanner

I recently found out that the out of the box scanner plugin will not scan more than 10 characters for a high density barcode (ex: CODE 39)

Since I use phonegap build, instead of reinventing the wheel, I would like to simply invoke an external barcode scanning app that can return the scanned value back to my app and I can continue from there.

How would I do that on PhoneGap?
I am looking for either a working sample/app or a code that I can use as reference to atleast do a POC.

Comment: you have to create a plugin that has an starActivityForResult, and onResult method. but don't expect all the user to have a scanning app

Comment: I understand that they user may not necessarily have the scanning app installed, but I would like to be able to invoke and retrieve the result. Would any of the plugins on https://build.phonegap.com/plugins work?

Comment: as far as I know, there is no plugin like that, but shouldn't be hard to create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up forking the barcodescanner repository on github and modifying the phonegap scanner plugin to only show a strip vs a box. This did resolve the issue.

Not the ideal solution, but was easier than architecting my own plugin